# como crear array a partir de un objeto

Tags: javascript

lo que necesito es que a medida que se capture su id este se valla guadando en un array y como este va almacenando los productos , pregunta si exite el objeto en dicho array
si es igual al id del boton entonces que me lo plasme en la consola esta repetido y sino  me dice no repetido
Productos es un objeto trae todos los elemntos del carro

```
    for (let index = 0; index < document.querySelectorAll('#productos_content>.id_n').length; 
     index++) {

let Productos = {
  id_n: id_ncap[index].textContent,
  id: idcap[index].textContent,
  codigo: codigocap[index].textContent,
  nombre: nombrecap[index.textContent],
  cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponiblecap[index].textContent,
  talla: tallacap[index].textContent,
  talla_ropa: talla_ropacap[index].textContent

  //img: itemImg,
  
  

};
```

**mi intento**
var arreglo=[]

```
  let itemProductos = Productos;

 arreglo.push(itemProductos)
 console.log(arreglo) 
 let itemProducto=arreglo.find(a=> a.id==id);
 //console.log(itemProducto)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Para crear un array a partir de un objeto en JavaScript, puedes seguir los siguientes pasos:**

**1. Declara un array vacio antes de iniciar el bucle**

```js
let arreglo = [];
```

**2. Dentro del bucle, crea el objeto productos con las propiedades deseadas**

```js
for (let index = 0; index < document.querySelectorAll('#productos_content>.id_n').length; index++) {
  let productos = {
    id_n: id_ncap[index].textContent,
    id: idcap[index].textContent,
    codigo: codigocap[index].textContent,
    nombre: nombrecap[index].textContent,
    cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponiblecap[index].textContent,
    talla: tallacap[index].textContent,
    talla_ropa: talla_ropacap[index].textContent
  };

  arreglo.push(productos); // agrega el objeto productos al array arreglo mediante el método push()
}
```

Ten en cuenta que este código agregaría cada objeto productos al array arreglo en cada iteración del bucle.

**3. Finalmente, puedes imprimir el array en la consola para verificar su contenido**

```js
console.log(arreglo);
```

Si deseas verificar si un objeto con el mismo id ya existe en el array antes de agregarlo, puedes utilizar el método find() como lo intentaste en tu código:

```js
let itemProducto = arreglo.find(a => a.id == id);
if (itemProducto) {
  console.log("Repetido");
} else {
  console.log("Id no repetido");
}
```

Recuerda que id debe ser el valor del botón que estás capturando. Asegúrate de asignarle el valor correcto a la variable id antes de utilizarla en la comparación.